# Is "...what doctors's career and life are like" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

> Through the practice at the hospital, I got to know what doctors's career and life are like.

Or should I say career**s** and live**s**?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: I suggest "what a doctor's career and life are like", which is a generic expression applying to doctors in general.  "Got to know" is fine, and "came to know" would be okay too, and slightly more formal.

Answer (score 1):

I was always told off at school for using 'got' It was frowned upon by all my English teachers.

'. . . I became acquainted with the careers and lives of Doctors."

Answer (score 0):

The possessive plural is ***doctors'***, without the extra 's'. I would say *careers* and *lives*, yes.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Comment: Matt, someone else downvoted your answer, and I'm asking why.  You can't vote on your own answers.